# Multiple page numbers on element of toc

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I make table of contents with multiple (I need exactly two) page numbers for some items? without creating a custom table. Properly, I have several different sections with same-named subsetions inside, e.g. theory/tasks/answers, but on toc they must be shown as one item.

[image: example]

**My Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

% show numeration only for subsections
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage\section{Theory}
\newcommand{\firstTitle}{First Subject}
\subsection{\firstTitle} some theory
\newcommand{\secondTitle}{Second Subject}
\subsection{\secondTitle} some theory

\newpage\section{Tasks}
\subsection{\firstTitle}some tasks
\subsection{\secondTitle}some tasks

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have up to three entries only? That is, one, two or three, but not four.

Comment: Triple columns on picture from existing book. Now I need only two entries (theory and tasks). Final toc should contain only **sub**section titles (may be small section icons at the top-right, but it doesnt matter)

Comment: The problem is not of putting two numbers at the end of the line -- the problem is the usage of the page numbers when the first entry is set, the line can't be written yet unless some expandable page reference mechanism is used, say with `\getrefpagenumber` from `refcount` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with the help of `nameref` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}

% show numeration only for subsections
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{4em} % more space for p1  -- p2  in  toc
\makeatother

\newcommand{\theory}[1]{%
\renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}%
\newcommand{\newsubsection}[1]{%
\subsection{##1}\label{\thesubsection}}%
\newpage\section{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\tasks}[1]{%
\newpage\section{#1}%
\renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{%
  \addtocontents{##1}{\protect\contentsline{##2}{##3}{\pageref{\thesubsection} --- \thepage}}}%
\renewcommand{\newsubsection}{%
\subsection{\nameref{\thesubsection}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\theory{Theory}

\newsubsection{First Subject}
some theory
\newsubsection{Second Subject}
some theory

\tasks{Tasks}

\newsubsection
some tasks
\newsubsection
some tasks

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work with `hyperref` too?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer as it is no, one only need a fourth  (implicite) argument `\addcontentsline` but i think this is another question.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but most likely, you're right -- it's another question